Erorr: BotMessage() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'person', 'UNCletter', 'spaces', and 'input_letter'
Cannot fix the error in line 100 - txt = 'Игра "Виселица" \n' + BotMessage(). BotMessage() does not accept 4 values. How to fix this error? And are there any other potential errors in the code?
import telebot
import random


Token = '8488484'
bot = telebot.TeleBot(Token)


hangman = ['''
    +---+
        |
        |
        |
       ===''', '''
    +---+
    0   |
        |
        |
       ===''', '''
    +---+
    0   |
    |   |
        |
       ===''', '''
    +---+
    0   |
   /|   |
        |
       ===''', '''
    +---+
    0   |
   /|\  |
        |
       ===''', '''
    +---+
    0   |
   /|\  |
   /    |
       ===''', '''
    +---+
    0   |
   /|\  |
   / \  |
       ===''']

words = 'акула баран бегемот верблюд ворона гепард гиена дельфин дятел ехидна жаба жираф заяц зебра игуана кабан козёл лебедь ленивец медведь мангуст норка носорог олень пингвин попугай собака суслик тюлень утконос фазан хорёк хомяк цапля чайка щегол ягуар ястреб'.split()

def RandomWord(WordList):
    word = random.randint(0, len(WordList) - 1)
    return WordList[word]

def interface(unCorrectLetters, CorrectLetter, Riddle):
    person = hangman[len(unCorrectLetters)]


    UNCletter = str('Неправильные буквы:', end=' ')
    for letter in unCorrectLetters:
        a = str(letter, end=' ')
    

    spaces = '_' * len(Riddle)
    for i in range(len(Riddle)):
        if Riddle[i] in CorrectLetter:
            spaces = spaces[:i] + Riddle[i] + spaces[i+1:]

    for letter in spaces:
        b = str(letter, end=' ')
    
    input_letter = 'Введите букву'
    #main(person, UNCletter, spaces, input_letter)
    
    return (person, UNCletter, spaces, input_letter)
    



def Guess(message, already):
    while True:
        guess = message.text.lower()
        if len(guess) != 1:
            bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Введите одну букву')
        elif guess in already:
            bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Вы уже называли эту букву, введите другую')
        elif guess not in 'абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя':
            bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Вводить можно только буквы')
        else:
            return guess

def BotMessage(person, UNCletter, spaces, input_letter):
        bot_message = person
        bot_message += "\n" + UNCletter
        bot_message += "\n" + spaces
        bot_message += "\n" + input_letter
        return bot_message

help = 'Привет! Это игра, в которой бот загадывает слово, а твоя задача его угадать. Чтобы начать игру, напиши команду /hanging'
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def main(message):
    if message.text == '/hanging':
        txt = 'Игра "Виселица" \n' + BotMessage()
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, txt)
        
            
        unCorrectLetters = ''
        CorrectLetter = ''
        Riddle = RandomWord(words)

        while True:
            interface_variables = interface(unCorrectLetters, CorrectLetter, Riddle)
            guess = Guess(message, unCorrectLetters + CorrectLetter)
            if guess in Riddle:
                CorrectLetter = CorrectLetter + guess

                allLetters = True
                for i in range(len(Riddle)):
                    if Riddle[i] not in CorrectLetter:
                        allLetters = False
                        break
                if allLetters:
                    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Вы угадали! Загаданное слово - "' + Riddle + '"!')
                    break

            else:
                unCorrectLetters = unCorrectLetters + guess

                if len(unCorrectLetters) == len(hangman) - 1:
                    interface(unCorrectLetters, CorrectLetter, Riddle)
                    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Вы исчерпали все попытки! Загаданное слово - "' + Riddle + '"!')
                    break

    elif message.text == "/help":
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, help)
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Я тебя не понимаю. Напиши /help.")
bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0, timeout=120)

The code runs without errors, but when the bot receives the message ‘/hanging’ it gives an error.
I've tried many ways, but none of them work.

when BotMessage() is called, it has no arguments, but it needs 4 arguments as per the function definition.

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Shortening the code to the error only. We can see that the error comes from calling a function that needs 4 arguments, but has none.
def main():

    # error is here > missing arguments !!
    txt = 'Игра "Виселица" \n' + BotMessage()

    # this will work...
    txt = 'Игра "Виселица" \n' + BotMessage('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')  
    print(txt)


def BotMessage(person, UNCletter, spaces, input_letter):
        bot_message = person
        bot_message += "\n" + UNCletter
        bot_message += "\n" + spaces
        bot_message += "\n" + input_letter
        return bot_message


if __name__=='__main__':
    main()


In the clean code above, it is clear that the first call to BotMessage() will fail, whereas the second call to BotMessage('a', 'b', 'c', 'd') will work.

But if I do that, python doesn't see these variables. How can I pass them to a function?
def main(message):
    if message.text == '/hanging':
        txt = 'Игра "Виселица" \n' + BotMessage(person, UNCletter, spaces, input_letter)
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, txt)


there are two standard ways to achieve this [1] the variables would need to be defined in the module that is calling the function, or [2] encapsulate the functions inside a class, which keeps everything self contained.
